# HTML-PDF using puppeteer in node

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf, pdf-conversion

I want to convert html to pdf. I have already tried phantomjs (which is giving timeout error all the time) and wkhtmltopdf (which is very slow,taking 10 mins to get downloaded) .

Now I tried puppeteer but I don't know how to do, first I tried installing puppeteer and its giving this error

> ERROR: Failed to download Chromium r662092! Set
>   "PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.

Can someone please help me to get over this html to pdf conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.npmrc` file you have to add the below line to get rid of this error,

```
puppeteer_skip_chromium_download=true
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you sir , It worked . I am new to this puppeteer, Can you guide me, how to use this with node

Comment: @Wolverine Glad that it worked!. Here is a step-by-step tutorial which you can follow => https://blog.risingstack.com/pdf-from-html-node-js-puppeteer/

Comment: But when trying to reload the website I am getting this error -->   Error: Chromium revision is not downloaded. Run "npm install" or "yarn install"  , On the website how can i solve this problem?

Comment: What happens when you do a `npm install` ?

Comment: It skipped Chromium Download --> **INFO** Skipping Chromium download. "PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD" was set in npm config.   That's why it's giving the above error. how to solve that ?

Comment: Can you try launching puppetter using, `const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ executablePath: "./node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/win64-XXXXXX/chrome-win/chrome.exe"});` 

**Note:** Check actual location/path in your `node_modules` and replace the `win-64-XXXXXX` accordingly.

Comment: I have tried this,It's giving the following error and I have tried other possibilities also using timeout error but it's the same.                                                               
 --> Error: Failed to launch chrome! spawn ../../node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/win64-70.0.3508.0/chrome-win/chrome.exe ENOENT

Comment: @Wolverine You just have to run "npm install" inside "/node_modules/peppeteer"